# How to keep a completed process in memory?

Tags: linux, windows, process

I have a program that has a large startup delay. (it needs to load lots of data from hard drive). So, I call it from the command line and provide it the name of input file, it processes that and prints output.

Now I need to figure out a way so that I can call the program again and again without incurring the startup delay. like a server? Is there a ready made solution for this? I have access to the source code, and can compile it again, but I don't have any idea how to code something up (haven't done systems programming)

Comment: Reading the file should put the contents into the disk cache, and assuming there is enough RAM to go around, it'll still be there on the second invocation. If the second time around it needs as long to read the data from disk (as opposed to processing it, which is a very different problem), double-check your disk caching settings.

Comment: what kind of UI (if any) does your app use?

Comment: @FrankThomas: It doesn't have a UI. It's not an app actually, I am using a program which takes in an english sentence and tells me what its semantic structure is. To do that it needs to load a large file, its database. I need to work with it interactively to run some experiments but there's a 120 second startup time every time (for every sentence) that's driving me crazy. If there's no solution I guess I could change the code and put the user input in a while(1) loop, but it would've been a pain if I didn't have source code.

Comment: "Remote Procedure Call(s)" (RPC) provides a way to do this that's not too hard (but not trivially easy, either).  I believe Sun Microsystems developed it, so I don't know whether it's available on Linux.

Comment: @Scott: I looked into RPC, i think it requires a server program. and the problem I am facing is that I want to wrap a process as a server? or rather what is the simplest way to convert a command line process into a server process?

Comment: @pushpen It actually doesn't *have* to be RPC, it can be just about anything that allows you to communicate with the program. You could just create a Unix or TCP socket and read lines from it. It's hard to be more specific without knowing what programming language the program is written in, but it's quite feasible to do so. This way you could do `while (1) { accept_connection_on_socket(); read_from_socket(); process_sentence(); write_answer_to_socket(); close_socket(); }` It's going to be a single connection, but it'll work.

Comment: @pushpen: If you can warp your program into a function, callable like `results = process_sentence(args)` à la @Janoszen’s suggestion, then RPC will create a simple server program to wrap that function.  By simple I mean single-threaded FIFO.  If you don’t need multi-threading or priority queues, you shouldn’t need to do any heavy lifting.

Comment: Scott and Janoszen: okay, I think I got it. Sockets seem to be the  way to go, simply because I am on windows+cygwin and I think I'll get more docs and guidance for sockets going forward. The program is written in C++/C so that's not a problem. Thanks everyone

Comment: @pushpen you may also want to look at .so/.dll files. Maybe you can put the whole program into a library and save your sanity by writing the socket / rpc handling in some scripting language like Python.

Comment: @janoszen: thanks again, I can clearly see that I didn't put in enough effort in my Operating Systems course 5 year ago. I have memories of studying about sockets/.so/.a but only now would I be using them in a real life problem.

Comment: @pushpen nobody does at school, but it's a darn interesting and rewarding subject once you dive into it. I'm a mainly coder, but this topic got me more than one job.